# Why is jquery-rails not loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have tried manually adding jquery in my rails app (3.2) and it works.

application.html.erb

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
```

Now i tried to replace this by using the rails-jquery gem, the css seems to load, however, the js does not work. What am i missing? How do I debug this? 
Gem file (followed by bundle install)

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Application.js

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
```

my Gemfile.lock looks like this.

```
specs:
  jquery-rails (2.0.2)
    railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
    thor (~> 0.14)
  jquery-ui-rails (4.0.5)
    railties (>= 3.1.0)
```

Comment: if you are using any custom layout then do you have javascript_include_tag in your layout?

Comment: yes I do - apologies- forgot to mention.

Comment: you need to have the javascript_include_tag even if you are using gem. It basically tells tells rails to include js inside your application.js where you are requiring all your js files

Comment: you don't have that tag when you are using gem?

Comment: yes- that what i meaant, I have the tag inside my application.js file already. I just forgot to mention in the original question. I have added it to my code above now. The problem still exists.

Comment: In your question you said that you replaced those tags with gem. Can you post your layout file and did you do bundle install after adding gem?

Comment: yes - I did a bundle install - I have updated the layout html file as well above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55807/discussion-between-user2675613-and-venomoustoad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the chat discussion the problem was that the **jquery installed was of a different version** than the plugin was using and hence giving errors.

You can install a particular version of jquery-rails by

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> version'
```